# How to convert CheckBox to boolean?

Tags: vb6, checkbox, boolean

If I have a CheckBox control called `chkTest`, what would be an accurate way to assign its state to a boolean variable?

```
Dim blnResult As Boolean
blnResult = [insert code here]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim blnResult As Boolean 
blnResult = chkTest = vbChecked
```

Comment: I'd write it as: `blnResult = (chkTest.Value = vbChecked)`

Comment: Why? The brackets are redundant.

Comment: It's all "redundant". But code is written for other programmers to read. The compiler is going to produce the same binary regardless. I think placing it in parentheses is much more readable. Explicitly accessing the `Value` property is also much more readable and reduces unwelcome surprises arising from the use of "default" properties.

Comment: What do mean by "it's all redundant"?  I'm just saying the brackets are redundant - because they are.

Comment: Did you read all the way to the end? I justified why I think the redundancy is preferable. I find your code very hard to read. It's not instantly clear to me what it means, especially in VB where the `=` operator doesn't have the same associativity as other C-based languages. The point of "it's all redundant" is that most of the code you write is going to be redundant. If you really cared about that, you'd be writing assembly, not in a high-level language. And the parentheses aren't the only thing that's redundant. Explicitly accessing the `Value` property is also unnecessary, but recommended.

Comment: I do agree that code should be readable, but there is another school of thought (read: Perl) that less code is best.

Comment: to make the most readable (and longest) code you could just use if...then...else...end if